# Commerce PDF error: Image not found or type unknown

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, image, dompdf

In the order template, this error shows up in the generated PDFs when adding standard JPG images.  We're running Commerce 1.2.x on PHP70.

It could be related to this [dompdf issue](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1118), but how do we fix it in Craft Commerce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting:

`'pdfAllowRemoteImages' => true,`

in your commerce.php config file.

Comment: That worked!  Stupid question but updates won't override the config file right?

Comment: No, the `commerce.php` config file you create in your `/config` directory will never be overridden. Just don't edit the config.php file in the commerce directory.

Comment: Thx.  Good thing I asked since I actually modified the core commerce/config.php which is definitely not the way to go, and didn't seem right either.  I've created a craft/config/commerce.php file now.  Thanks again!